# what is the difference between Locationmanager.locationListener and com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener?

Tags: android, location, google-play-services, locationlistener

I found implementations of both **locationListener** on a single *Activity* of an android project. What are the differences?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's because there are two totally different ways you can do it. The first is using Android APIs from **android.location.LocationListener**, and the second is using Google Play Services APIs **com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener**.
[Here is the complete overview](http://www.rahuljiresal.com/2014/02/user-location-on-android/)!

Answer (score 0):

One android phone may don't support com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener but support Locationmanager.locationListener